# Assigning array of objects in smarty

Tags: php, smarty

I want to use a loop in smarty to read an object value which i will be passing from controller later on.

```
{foreach from=$foo->bars item=bar}
    {$bar->product->name}
    {$bar->code}
{/foreach}
```

To initialize this, i wrote the following code in smarty file:

```
{php}
    $bar1->product->name =  "prod1";
    $bar1->code = "BC5E";

    $bar2->product->name =  "prod2";
    $bar2->occasionName = "XW9D";

    $this->assign($foo->bars, array($bar1,$bar2);
{/php}
```

But this gives me an error, is this the right way to create an object in Smarty ?

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->assign($foo->bars, array($bar1,$bar2));
```

You forgot to close last `)`.

Comment: still, $foo->bars is empty

Answer (score 0):

Can you please do all the execution with the object on the php page and then you can assign the final array on to the smarty and use easily on the .tpl page this is the best way.

Try not to process data on the .tpl page process all the data on php page and assign it to .tpl  and then just show it.

Smarty is a template engine and is designed for view(presentation) mainly.

Write the foreach loop on .php create array output and assign to tpl.

Comment: as i say .. this is for testing and i will be getting data from controller later on.